# Specifying the Order of Start Menu Shortcuts

Tags: vb.net, startmenu

I created shortcuts for some of my exe's in the program menu. For example, I might create shortcuts for a.exe, v.exe, and g.exe. By default, it aligns as a, g, v (in alphabetical order). I want to place my shortcuts in a different order, such as (v, a, g).

In short, I want to be able to change the order for the shortcuts it creates to something other than alphabetical order.

I am using wshshellobject in vb. I created a dll; through that I created my shortcuts

Comment: How is this a C# question or even programming related for that matter?

Comment: Presumably the shortcuts were created programattically? This could definitely use more detail though.

Comment: How exactly are you creating the shortcuts?

Comment: Are you talking about the windows start-menu? What's wshshellobject??

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're trying to modify the order of your shortcuts on the Start Menu, I'm not sure this is possible to do programatically (which is a shame - I've fired up the uninstallers for many apps in Vista/7 by typing their names and just hitting  without looking!).

Microsoft's Raymond Chen posted this on his blog some time ago:

> The classic Start menu and the "All
>   Programs" portion of the Windows XP
>   Start menu permit you to customize the
>   order of the shortcuts that appear
>   there. You can use drag/drop to
>   rearrange them, or force them to be
>   sorted by name. But why is there no
>   programmatic interface to these
>   actions?
>
> Because the power would be used for
>   evil far more than it would be used
>   for good.

More info here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/19/636823.aspx

Comment: Wow, this question is old. Stack Overflow default sorting fail :-(

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering old questions! Someone might find them helpful later, and you might get a necromancer badge for your troubles :)